How to Replace the Second Character with Emacs Regex?
Replace the first or second Character
xxx-xxx-xxx => xxx-xxx*xxx
or
xxx-xxx-xxx => xxx*xxx-xxx 


Not clear what you're asking. Please provide a step-by-step recipe, from emacs -Q, to clarify. Replacement of what character, where (buffer? string?).

I assumed the character was - from the examples and  the where is string from the replace-regexp-in-string tag (which @Drew deleted). But I agree: it needs clarification.

I was guessing it was the * in the examples that indicated a position. Or that something else was meant by "character" than an actual character, with xxx being that something (at each location). But your guess sounds better.

Here's one way to do such replacements. To replace the first dash:
(setq s "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx")
"xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"

(replace-regexp-in-string "\\([^-]*\\)-\\(.*\\)" "\\1*\\2" s)
"xxx*xxx-xxx-xxx"

That says: "match a sequence of non-dashes (and remember it as subexp 1), followed by a dash, followed by the rest (the rest is remembered as subexp 2); replace the match by subexp 1, followed by an asterisk, followed by subexp 2." IOW, we match the whole string and remember parts of it to use in the replacement.
Replacing the last dash is easier because of the greediness of the * operator:
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\(.*\\)-\\(.*\\)" "\\1*\\2" s)
"xxx-xxx-xxx*xxx"

That also suggests a slightly easier method of replacing the first one: make the first star operator non-greedy:
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\(.*?\\)-\\(.*\\)" "\\1*\\2" s)
"xxx*xxx-xxx-xxx"

Replacing the second one is more cumbersome:
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\([^-]*-[^-]*\\)-\\(.*\\)" "\\1*\\2" s)
"xxx-xxx*xxx-xxx"

This says: "match a sequence of non-dashes, followed by a dash, followed by a sequence of non-dashes (and remember the whole thing as subexp 1), followed by a dash (i.e. the second dash), followed by the rest (which is remembered as subexp 2); then replace it by subexp 1, followed by an asterisk, followed by subexp 2."
Replacing the third, fourth, fifth... occurrence becomes increasingly more cumbersome and the expression becomes increasingly less readable but it's doable.
There may be better ways (the doc string of replace-regexp-in-string suggests another method for replacing the first one, but I'm not sure if it's any easier than what I showed above), but the moral of the story IMO is: if you can avoid using a regexp, you are better off in the long run. Using rx to construct the regexps might be slightly more readable, but still, if you don't have to use regexps, don't use regexps.
As an example, you can use a loop to do the counting (which is simple), rather than have the regexp to do the counting "on its fingers":
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert s)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (when (search-forward "-" nil t 2)
    (replace-match "*"))
  (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max)))

No regexp in sight! Here the counting is done in a loop inside search-forward, so you don't even need an explicit loop (but you can use a while instead of a when: that will replace every second match). And all you have to do to replace the third occurrence e.g. is change the 2 to a 3. See the doc string of the function with C-h f search-forward.

You also can make use of the \{\} construct to have the regexp count for you as in (replace-regexp-in-string "\\([^-]*\\(-[^-]*\\)\\{2\\}\\)-" "\\1*" s) to replace the 3rd dash, change the number as required. There is no need to match the tail part btw.

You are right of course, but I didn't want to get into the weeds of regexps. My point was that readability is important and none of these regexps pass that test.
